# Passing a value dynamically through a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

The function check a input checkbox depending on it's value.

It was working properly until I tried to pass the value "dynamically" through the button. I'm missing something, but can't see what it is.

```
function fill(value_id)
{           
    $('input[type=checkbox][value='value_id']').prop('checked', true);
}


<div class="btn open-modal" data-modal="somemodal" onclick='fill("12-12")'>check</div>
```

Any explanation on the solution is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
$('input[type=checkbox][value='value_id']').prop('checked', true);
                              ^        ^
                               Syntax Error
```

To

```
 $('input[type=checkbox][value="'+ value_id + '"]').prop('checked', true);
```

You got syntax error

Comment: Many thanks! I was using `console.log("entered fill()" + value_id)` to see if at least I was entered the function... and didn't notice the concatenation...

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the console for errors. Beware at the concatanation and quotes when trying to escape the value. This should do the trick

```js
function fill(value_id) {
  $('input[type=checkbox][value="' + value_id + '"]').prop('checked', true);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn open-modal" data-modal="somemodal" onclick='fill("12-12")'>check</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use + (concatenate) operator to concatenate string and variable.

```
$('input[type=checkbox[value='+value_id+']').prop('checked', true);
```

```js
function fill(value_id)
{           
    $('input[type=checkbox[value='+value_id+']').prop('checked', true);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="btn open-modal" data-modal="somemodal" onclick='fill("12-12")'>check</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing add plus (+) between variable and string. You can use this snippet

```js
function fill(value_id) {
  $('input[type=checkbox][value=' + value_id + ']').prop('checked', true);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn open-modal" data-modal="somemodal" onclick='fill("12-12")'>check</div>


<input value="12-12" type="checkbox"></input>
```